# read CSV files error with numpy and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

the error message :

```
eyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Service'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25872\2219816057.py in <module>
----> 1 train['Service'].value_counts()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3456             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3457                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3458             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3459             if is_integer(indexer):
   3460                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'Service'
```

My Code:

```
#Get the feature names to rename all the columns
features = pd.read_csv('NSL-KDD Features - Sheet2.csv')
def rename_column(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.rename(columns = features['Feature Name'])
    return df

#imports to load and modify text files, dataframes
import pandas as pd
#settig this option to see the entire results of a dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000)
#loading training, testing data; renaming the column names
def load_data():
    train = pd.read_csv('KDDTrain+.txt', sep=',', header=None)
    train = rename_column(train)
    print(train)
    test = pd.read_csv('KDDTest+.txt', sep=",", header=None)
    test = rename_column(test)
    return train, test
train, test = load_data()
```

`Hello everyone I am new to Python and I am in a Data Analytics course and am having trouble with one of my problems. The following is the problem, my code, then the error message.

> I tried to change different pandas and numpy versions.
> pandas version : 1.3.5
> numpy  version : 1.21.6

the train.head is working fine and showing all the columns.

any suggestions ???`

Comment: `train` has no column `Service`. Why do you expect it to have one?

Comment: the fourth feature is Service of NSL-KDD dataset

Comment: Feature Name
Duration
Protocol_Type 
Service
Flag
 Src Bytes                   
 Dst Bytes                   
 Land                        
 Wrong Fragment

Answer (score 0):

In the error it says: `KeyError: 'Service'`. This means that there is an `KeyError`, i.e. `train['Service']` does not exist.

Maybe the key (`Service`) should be written in lowercase or uppercase or it is just wrong. You can use `print(train.columns)` to see which columns are present in your dataframe.

Also make sure that this works as intended:

```
def rename_column(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.rename(columns = features['Feature Name'])
    return df
```

Here `features['Feature Name']` should be a dictionary with old name and new name [1].

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html